# Restrict the output using the perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging, less-unix

I'm using the perl debugger to analyze a large hash. However, when I display it (with `x`) it fills up the display and I can't see the start of the hash. Is there a way to pipe the output through something similar to `less`?

Comment: Use Data::Dumper for Output. So you can print it in a file and work wich a text tool.

Comment: for slightly better output, I'd recommend [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at Devel::Trace that you can run via the command line and capture output. Run with `perl -d:Trace program`.  [http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trace](http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aTrace)

Data::Dumper is also very useful.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using Dumper to just output the hash to a file. Thanks for the recommendation.